# How to pass nltk.FreqDist a big splitted list or file

Tags: python, string, loops, iterator, nltk

I'm trying to pass a big splitted list to the function 'FreqDist' to find the most frequent words.

I splitted the list using pickle as follow:

```
import nltk
import cPickle as pickle
import sys
import os
import itertools as it
for no,i in enumerate(it.islice(it.count(), 3, 33+3, 3)):
    if no == 0:
        fil = tokens[0:i]
    else:
        fil = tokens[i-3+1:i+1]

    file_name = "/tmp/words/text" + str(no+1) + '.p'
    files = open(file_name, "wb")
    pickle.dump(fil, files)
    files.close()
```

Now I'd like to pass the files using a class operator as follow:

```
class Passer(object):
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path = path

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.path):
            with open(self.path + "/" + fname, "rb") as f:
                fil = pickle.load(f)
                yield fil

passer = Passer(path="/tmp/words")   
words = nltk.FreqDist(passer)
```

Unfortunately, doing it in this way I got this error:

```
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'Passer'
```

Does someone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Iterators in Python 2 must define the `next` method (no underscores).

Comment: That's mean that what I did would work on python 3, right?

Comment: `__next__` would work on Python 3, yes. There's no cPickle in Python 3, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
FreqDist(chain(*[word_tokenize(line) for line in open('in.txt')]))
```

E.g.:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ echo """This is a foo bar sentence
> Not any more hahaha""" > in.txt
alvas@ubi:~$ cat in.txt 
This is a foo bar sentence
Not any more hahaha
alvas@ubi:~$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec 15 2015, 16:46:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
fType "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from nltk import FreqDist
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> FreqDist(chain(*[word_tokenize(line) for line in open('in.txt')]))
FreqDist({'a': 1, 'bar': 1, 'sentence': 1, 'This': 1, 'is': 1, 'hahaha': 1, 'Not': 1, 'foo': 1, 'any': 1, 'more': 1})
```

Comment: This is merely a workaround. Perhaps you should explain how to get rid of the `TypeError` as well?

Comment: Hi alvas thanks a lot for your answer. It helped me to do this generator: 'nltk.FreqDist(it.chain([word for word in pickle.load(open(file_name)) 
    for file_name in os.listdir("/tmp/words/")]))'. It works very well! Is there any possibility to do something similar using a Class and a __iter__ function? Thanks again

Comment: I think it might be an overkill to create your own class to read a corpus. Take a look at the corpus readers already coded in NLTK. Those might help you, https://github.com/nltk/nltk/tree/develop/nltk/corpus/reader

Comment: Can you post a sample of how you file(s) / directory look like? Then we can find the correct corpus reader that will suit your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I stored the following text into 11 pickle files:

```
text = 'The European Union’s plan to send refugees fleeing Syria’s civil war back to Turkey en masse could be illegal, a top UN official has said, as concerns mounted that Greece,Greece2'
```

The directory is called words (path=/tmp/words) and there are 11 filles named testo1, testo2 and so on. Now I found out the right comprehension to reach my goal:

```
nltk.FreqDist([word for f in os.listdir("/tmp/words/") for word in pickle.load(open("/tmp/words/"+f))])
```

Now, it seems that everything is working but I am asking myself if this will feed the FreqDist step by step or if it is loading the list first and than processes it. Because my idea was to load and process the files step by step without to load all once to save memory.

Thanks again for the help.